# What important edge cases need to be considered when writing sync algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Syncing is often regarded as being complex, error prone, and time consuming to handle properly. So for those of you who have written syncing code, what are the important edge cases to be aware of? I'd like to have a good idea of these so I can design from the edge cases in.

Specifically, the kind of thing I'm interested in is the situation where there are two or more clients that can make updates and a server mediating. The clients will have intermittent access to the server and can handle temporary inconsistency. (So the system is "eventually consistent" I believe it's called.)

Comment: "a read-only server mediating" eh? How can a read-only server mediate anything? If it can't pass information from one client to the other, then the clients must also be in communication, so how is this any different from a purely P2P system?

Comment: The clients wouldn't communicate. This is not a very helpful comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost exactly three years later, this is the kind of thing I was looking for. Issue 10 of objc.io goes into some detail regarding sync.

http://www.objc.io/issue-10/

Answer (score 1):

Some research that might be relevant: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/papers/index.shtml#Synchronization

This is from the guy that wrote the Unison file synchronizer, among other tools.